# How can I project several objects towards a plane while respecting object bounds?

Tags: modeling, scripting

I have a situation like below with several objects and I want to project them towards the plane X=0 while preventing objects from colliding. Basically each object goes as close as it can towards the plane without intersecting anything else.

Going from:
[image: before projecting]

To:
[image: after projecting]

Is there a way to do this quickly and easily for any number of objects?

Comment: the best thing I could think of is enable grid snapping and then adjust the settings as needed

Comment: You can orient those objects along Z axis and set up a rigid body simulation (the big cube will be collision, the rest of them - active Rigid Bodies), then play it and wait until they are stuck on that surface. Use mesh bounds as rigid body options